# Facebook SDK session not opening

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to put a `Facebook login` on my `Android` app, but the `Session` is not being opened. Why is happening?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.v("SESSION OPEN","");

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: have u give internet permission in manifest?

Comment: @DixitPatel yes I gave it that permission.

Comment: If the user you're using is a developer/admin/tester of the app, they should be able to log in in sandbox mode. You should also be able to drill into the FacebookAuthorizationException, and see the cause of the error.

Comment: What is the value of the exception parameter?

Comment: This issue was awnsered on the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062095/facebook-android-sdk-does-not-open-session-after-login